# ASP.NET Get the id of the dropdownlist that placed inside of a repeater

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, repeater

I'am trying to get the id of a dropdownlist that placed in a repeater in order to make some ajax calls but i can't do it. How can i make it possible my implementation is below:

Ajax function

```
function ShowCurrentTime() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebForm1.aspx/showColor",
        data: '{name: "' + $("#<%=colorList1.ClientID%>").val() + '" }',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: OnSuccess,
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    });
}
function OnSuccess(response) {
    alert(response.d);
}
```

User interface implementation

```
<ajaxToolkit:TabPanel ID="TabPanel5" runat="server">
                <HeaderTemplate>Show Shoes</HeaderTemplate>
                <ContentTemplate runat="server">
                    <input id="btnGetTime" type="button" value="Show Current Time" onclick = "al()" />                                        
                    <asp:Repeater ID="shoeRepeater" OnItemCreated="shoeRepeater_ItemCreated" runat="server">
                        <HeaderTemplate></HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>

                            <table border="1" style="border-color:#ff9900; width:400px; font-weight:bold; font-family:'Oswald', Arial, sans-serif;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td rowspan="6" style="width:150px; height:150px;">
                                        <image src="shoeImages/<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ImagePath") %>"></image>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"BrandName") %> <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ModelName") %> 
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Price: $<%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Price") %>
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Size: <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Size") %>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <asp:DropDownList ID="colorList1" runat="server">
                                            <asp:ListItem>asdas</asp:ListItem>
                                            <asp:ListItem>asf</asp:ListItem>
                                        </asp:DropDownList>
                                        Color: <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"PrimaryColor") %> - <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"SecondaryColor") %>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        Quantity: <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"Quantity") %>
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate></FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JS ajax function,

```
 var oObject= document.getElementById('colorList1');
 var id = oObject.id;
```

Comment: After i get the id, how can i get the value of selected option from dropdownlist ?

Comment: wire up a jS event to the dropdown, <asp:DropDownList ID="colorList1" runat="server" onchange="ddl(this)">

<script type="text/javascript">
        function ddl(ddl) {
            alert(ddl.value);
        }
 </script>, give it a try!

Comment: there is no onchange method for asp:DropDownList

Comment: Lol, sorry I must be dreaming, http://forums.asp.net/t/1803678.aspx?Calling+javascript+function+from+asp+DropDownList+onchange+event+

Comment: No worries, we all do that sometimes, Your welcome !